# MS Word 2010 over double RDP is lagging

Tags: microsoft-word, remote-desktop

Quick back story, a user has a desktop in my office, and they have an old laptop at home, which they use to RDP onto their desktop. We could not give them a direct link to their desktop, however we have a server which they could RDP onto first, and then RDP onto their machine. The issue we're having, is that certain word documents take a long time to open, and sometimes crash.

They can open the documents fine on their own machine when they're in the office, and can open them when they use the laptop on the internal link to their desktop as well. Its not the internet connection cause chances are it would have dropped out instead of crashing word, its not the laptop cause it shouldn't be playing a factor in this, its not the desktop cause they use it all the time with no problems, and its not the server they hop onto first cause its used by many other users who also experience no problems.

At this point, I'm at a loss because I have no idea whats going wrong. Anybody else know or have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using an RDP gateway, or actually two nested RDP sessions? Another solution is a VPN. Having RDP running on a public-facing server is just bad news, in general.

Comment: Have you looked at the error logs to see WHY Word thinks it is crashing?